# Calling an Action Method from Javascript in PHP MVC

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, phalcon

I am working on php phalcon with XAMPP server.

I have a controller called `PrescriptionsController`. It has several action methods. In the `index` view, I fill a `<form>` to make the prescription then when I hit a `save` button, a javascript function is called which calls another action method in the controller.

The thing is that the I can dynamically increase the number of textboxes depending upon the number of medicines I want to prescribe to the patient. This is why it is necessary that when I hit save, the javascript function is called in order to check the number of textboxes and the values that they contain.

Now, I wish to know that how can I achieve this? Okay I can read the values from the textboxes and insert them into an array, but I actually have two arrays and I want to know how to pass them as parameters to the action method which I am calling in the javascript function? One more thing, if I do something like this:

```
<script>
function generate()
{
//necessary code
open("actionmethod");
}
</script>
```

Along with this:

```
<form method="post">
<-- form body -->
<input type="submit" onclick="generate()">
</form>
```

My `$_POST` returns empty. How can I solve this too?

So my two questions are:
How to pass parameters to action methods called in javascript?
How to get $_POST values?

NOTE: I need two submit buttons and I am using two as well. One to preview and the other to save.

Comment: you should begin by naming your inputs

Comment: thanks but my inputs are already named. This is just a little demo of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should think of an alternative way to do it, you could for example, suffix every input name with its Id, set a counter for the number of inputs. Every time you add an input, you increase the count. Then when you save, you just do a for loop to get the inputs values using `document.getElementsByName("InputNameId")[0].value`.

You can also just add ids to the inputs and get it by `document.getElementById('InputNameId').value` !

All the syntax is assuming you are using pure javascript.

Comment: Yes I am using pure javascript for the counting part. Okay so that will help me get the count but what about my submission issue of the form?

Comment: You can do `actionmethod(array1, array2)`, the function in which you deliver the post request as ajax, i guess.

Comment: I am a little confused. Let's just say I want to submit a form through javascript, how do I do that?

Comment: you can do `document.forms['FormName'].submit();` or you do an ajax request, if you don't want the page to reload.

Comment: I just tried the submit thing and it still gives me an empty $_post. I will try the ajax request next.. Umm any thoughts on how to do it?

Comment: Make sure you specified the action in the form tag : `<form id='myform' action='controller.php'>` , for ajax learn more at http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp